# Add mac address in rsyslog template

Tags: logging, unix, rsyslog, syslog, unix-shell

I am trying to add system/device mac address in syslog. No solution is working for me. Following command gives me mac address, just wanted to use in rsyslog template.

```
mac_addr=$(ifconfig en0 | awk '/ether/ {print $2}')
```

**template**

```
template(name="tpl3" type="string" string="%TIMESTAMP:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% MAC=%$mac_addr% %syslogtag%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n")
```

Want to replace $mac_addr with value.

**rsyslogd version**

```
rsyslogd  8.2112.0 (aka 2021.12) compiled with:
    PLATFORM:               x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    PLATFORM (lsb_release -d):      
    FEATURE_REGEXP:             Yes
    GSSAPI Kerberos 5 support:      Yes
    FEATURE_DEBUG (debug build, slow code): No
    32bit Atomic operations supported:  Yes
    64bit Atomic operations supported:  Yes
    memory allocator:           system default
    Runtime Instrumentation (slow code):    No
    uuid support:               Yes
    systemd support:            Yes
    Config file:                /etc/rsyslog.conf
    PID file:               /run/rsyslogd.pid
    Number of Bits in RainerScript integers: 64

See https://www.rsyslog.com for more information.
```

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: I need to send syslogs to a central place and filter using Mac address.

Comment: Can the program that generates the log add the mac address itself ? I'm not sure that rsyslog can run commands like you want.
Otherwise you could have a look to "omprog" plugin.